# .Net / Asp.Net Web api Background Tasks

Tags: asp.net, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, background-task

I am looking for an options to execute recurring background tasks. The background Task would call the external REST GET request and update the status accordingly in the application database.

Which one of the following would be appropriate, considering that we do not like to maintain separate web.config between the application and the scheduler/task app. Looking for Simple option in .NET/Asp.NET web API context -  not looking for any separate installation / 3rd party.

1. Scheduled task - believe we need to create those many scheduled tasks in a server which points to those many databases? maintainability is a concern?
2. windows service
3. Asp.Net background task options
4. any other better option?

Please provide your insights for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend looking at Hangfire to implement background tasks

This works better than a windows service in a cloud environment and supports fire-and-forget and repeat tasks/processing etc and integration is really seamless.

I just noticed your non-3rd party comment, not sure if you mean commercial component, but this is free, via nuget, if that helps?

see: https://www.hangfire.io